# A problem with functions and Infinite expression 1/0 encountering

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, function-construction

Following code (function) makes integrals and then replace `f[x]` with `Cos` functions and calculate the definite parametric integrals as it is shown below :

```
DoGenerateIntegrals[Number_] :=

Block[{GeneratingIntegrals, COS, LimitCOS},

GeneratingIntegrals = 
Array[Integrate[
   Symbol["f"][x], {x, Symbol["x" <> ToString[2 # - 1]], 
    Symbol["x" <> ToString[2 #]]}] &, Number];

COS = Total[
 GeneratingIntegrals /. 
  f[x] -> Cos[((i \[Pi])/L) x] Cos[((j \[Pi])/L) x]];
LimitCOS = Limit[COS, i -> j];

{COS, LimitCOS}];
```

Then :

```
In[1]:= Produce = DoGenerateIntegrals[2]
```

By using the results of the `In[1]` :

```
CosInt = Which[i != j, Produce[[1, 1]], i == j, Produce[[1, 2]]];
```

Which `CosInt` is to avoid encountering Infinite expression (`1/0`).

Now it will use in a code like below in a matrix :

```
List1 = Table[0, {i, 1, 6}, {j, 1, 6}];


Do[Do[List1[[i + 2, j + 2]] = CosInt, {j, 1, 2}], {i, 1, 2}];

List1 // MatrixForm
```

In `DoGenerateIntegrals[]` when the integrals evaluates with mentioned `f[x]`, there will  `i-j` in their denominator of their fractions which cause Infinite expression in `List1` calculation. In order to avoid encountering Infinite expression (`1/0`), I use `LimitCOS` and `CosInt` to calculate the circumstances of `i=j` . But after calculation, it will face encountering Infinite expression (`1/0`) with following error:

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.>>
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.>>
```

I wonder why this is happening; however, I have used some strategies to avoid it.

Comment: Related, I believe: [What is the cleanest way to prevent divide-by-zero warnings?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5422/121)

Comment: Also, FYI: `CosInt * BoxMatrix[0, 6] // MatrixForm`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : I think the problem is not about "Indeterminate expression",the major problem about above code is that when I  put `Produce[[1,1]]` and `Produce[[1,2]]` into `CosInt`, `CosInt` can not understand that `Produce[[1,1]] and Produce[[1,1]]` are also functions of `i and j`. In spite of using strategies to avoid infinite expression encountering, it ignore `Which` loop and just uses the `Produce[[1,1]]`. I can not understand why this is happening !!

Comment: I wish to help, but I would like to address your questions in the order they appeared.  Will you please reply to my requests in my answer to [A problem with set values](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46255/121) first?

Comment: I see that you Accepted my answer there.  Thanks (really), but I am still hoping for the opportunity to show you "a better way."  I will you describe what you want that code to accomplish?  That is, what is your "real problem?"

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : Please refer to  [A problem with set values](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46255/a-problem-with-set-values) and I will describe what I want that code to accomplish?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 1):

*[Update notice: Yesterday, I had some time to play, so I thought I'd help the site out and go through some of the unanswered Q's, answering some and voting to close others. I agree with Oleksandr that this question is of highly localized interest, as well as a newbie mistake.  But I suppose that if this answer, which is the answer, is not found useful by the community, then this question should be closed and probably even deleted.]*

The problem is that the whole of `Produce` is evaluated before its part can be extracted in your double-`Do` loop.  Since sometimes `i` and `j` have the same value when `Produce` is evaluated, you get division by zero before the non-offending part is obtained.

Try

```
CosInt = Which[
  i != j, Evaluate@ Produce[[(*1,*) 1]],
  i == j, Evaluate@ Produce[[(*1,*) 2]]];
```

Then your loop for filling `List1` runs without error messages.

(Since `Produce` is a simple list of two elements, the part specification `...[[1, 2]]` causes an error.  `Produce` would have to be a two-dimensional array for it to be correct.)